# Force non-class functions to exist?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a class which I call `MyString`.  And I want it to be a abstract class that looks something like this:

```
class MyString{
  virtual MyString* operator+(char* other) = 0;
  virtual MyString* operator+(MyString* other) = 0;
};
```

The `operator+` is just being used as a concatenation operator.  My question is how do I force another operator like this:

```
MyString* operator+(char* first, MyString* other) = 0;
```

To be implemented by the class that derives from this class.

Note that this function would normally have to be outside of the class.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How would this work? You can't do virtual dispatch on a free function. So you would need to make `append` a (pure) `virtual` member function, and force it that way. Then you can call `append` in your `operator+`, which is only defined at the top level of the hierarchy.

Comment: Also, do you *really* want to use `+` for `append`? Think about the semantics. For instance, the expectation is that `+` is usually commutative: `1+2 == 2+1 == 3`, but `"a"+"b" != "b"+"a"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, C++ is not C, and pointers are to be generally avoided.  You want this:

```
class MyString{
  virtual MyString* operator+(char* other) = 0;
  virtual MyString* operator+(MyString& other) = 0;
};
```

Second, you forgot `const` and `public`, so you really want this:

```
class MyString{
public:
  virtual MyString* operator+(const char* other) const = 0;
  virtual MyString* operator+(const MyString& other) const = 0;
};
```

Third, for your task, if I understood it correctly, you need:

```
class MyString{
public:
  virtual MyString* operator+(const char* other) const = 0;
  virtual MyString* operator+(const MyString& other) const = 0;
  virtual MyString* append_to(const char* other) const = 0; // x.append_to(y) is y+x
};

inline MyString* operator+(const char* x, const MyString& y) {return y.append_to(x);}
```

PS: changed MyString to MyString* as a return type.

Comment: The semantics of this look off -- although you *should* avoid pointers as you say, to take advantage of virtuals you need to move to a pointer implementation, and the virtual methods would be on the internal class, not the public facing class.

Comment: @Hurkyl - correct. I changed MyString to MyString* as a return type.